# How to fix environment variables not working while running from system-d service in Go

Tags: go

I am using `os.Getenv("APP_PATH")` to read from the system environment variables and it works fine when running the build of the application normally. But I need to run this Go program as a service which I have done using systemd in which case it cannot read the environment variables. Is there any way of resolving this?

Comment: Why you cannot read variable in case of systemd?

Comment: Add your service definition file to the question, otherwise we can only guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can follow along from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940679/pass-environment-variables-to-services-started-with-systemctl) to make the use of the environment variables. The way I am using to implement environment variables in my project is [GODOTENV](https://github.com/joho/godotenv) go library. It is very easy to implement and platform independent.

Simply run

`err = godotenv.Load(filepath.Join(path_dir, ".env"))`

and you are done. Now you can use you code `os.Getenv("APP_PATH")` to read the keys from your `.env` file and it works perfectly fine with systemd service.

Comment: What is the `filePath` and `path_dir`?

Comment: `filePath` you need to import using `import "path/filepath"` and `path_dir` is where your .env file is

Answer (score 8):

It depends on how you're running your systemd service. Systemd provide a bunch of derictive you should use:

```
[Unit]
Description=My service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=user
Group=user
EnvironmentFile=/home/user/env_file
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c -l '/home/user/go_program'
# ... other directive goes here

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- `EnvironmentFile` - the file with ENV variables, that file will be loaded for you by systemd.
- `User`, `Group` - under which user and group the program should run.
- `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c -l '/home/user/go_program'` - the `-l` options makes [bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html), so the variable in your `.bash_profile` will be loaded(see `User` and `Group` section).

Answer (score 6):

We have our environment variables in a .env file and use [godotenv](https://github.com/joho/godotenv)

```
    import {
       "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    }

    func main() {

        dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        environmentPath := filepath.Join(dir, ".env")
        err = godotenv.Load(environmentPath)
        fatal(err)
    }
```

and it works when we run our apps in daemon mode